# static functions vs normal class function

Tags: ios, swift, performance, memory-management, static

I need to show an activity indicator quite often in my application so i have written a class like this.
import Foundation

```
class ActivityIndicator
{
    static func startActivityIndicator(mainView:UIView)
    {
        let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
        activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.WhiteLarge
        activityIndicator.color = UIColor.grayColor()
        activityIndicator.center = mainView.center
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        mainView.addSubview(activityIndicator)
    }
}
```

I have made the "startActivityIndicator" function static just because it looks clean implementation. I just want to know is there any hit on performance or memory wise if we make loads of static functions in an app.
Can anyone shed a light please?

Comment: I do something like this but instead of making a new class I extend the UIViewController class.

Comment: I could have done that but i need a generic implementation that i can show on different view controller , navigation controller , tableviewcontroller or evern in custom views e.t.c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the hood a static function differs from an instance function only in how it takes its implicit parameters: instance functions take one implicit parameter for `self`, while static functions take no implicit parameters for anything.

As far as the code for the function is concerned, there is no penalty for a function being static or non-static. Same goes for performance: static functions are simplest lightweight "packages" of executable code; calling them carries no additional costs.

Your particular implementation, however, may benefit from storing `activityIndicator` in a variable to avoid re-creating it in each static call. Moreover, this would make it easier for you to *remove* the activity indicator from superview once the activity has finished. If you would like to use a single `activityIndicator`, you could keep your function static, and add a class variable for `activityIndicator`. Otherwise, you should make multiple instances of `ActivityIndicator` class, each having its own `activityIndicator` instance variable. In this case, `startActivityIndicator` should become an instance method as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well the amazing thing is using static methods is better as far as performance is considered since you do not have to create any instance of the class to call them.

So if you want to call it from 100 different places, for a normal function you would create 100 instances of the class, utilising memory, while for static you wouldnt create any instance so memory usage is reduced big time.

P.S.: the number 100 is just to show the intensity of the difference.